# byte[] to be stored in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a byte[] which is actually an image.

i want to store it in Oracle 11g. I created a BLOB Column in my Table. and by following i tried to insert it.

> ```
> String imageStr = "xyz...."
> byte[] data = imageStr.getBytes(); 
> String sQuery = "insert into Table (LOCATION , BLOB_DATA) Values ('Lahore', data) ";
> ```

It throws exception "**java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number**"

I searched it and found that this type of query should be done via **PreparedStaement**.

so i did something following

> ```
> PreparedStatement prepStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement("insert into Table (LOCATION, BLOB_DATA) values(?,?);
> prepStmt.setString(1, 'Lahore');
> prepStmt.setBytes(2, bytes);
> ```

I start getting error on **dbConnection.prepareStatement(String)** because the DBConnection class is not Java Native class.

It's a Custom class made by Earlier Developers for Database Connection and it do not has **prepareStatement(String)** function in it.

So what to do now??

**1. Should i create a method prepareStatement(String) in DBConnection class?**

**2. Should i go for first approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at my example to store image in db

```
   Statement s;
         Connection c;      
         FileInputStream fis;
         PreparedStatement ps;
         File file; 
         try
        {
               Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");//your driver
               c=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:image","scott","tiger");//password and name changes according to your db
               s=c.createStatement();   
               st.execute("Create table ImageStoring(Image_No number(5),Photo blob)");
         }
         catch(Exception e1) 
        {
               e1.printStackTrace();
         }  

         try
        {       
               file=new File"D:/ARU/Aruphotos/4.jpg");
               fis=new FileInputStream(file);

               Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
               c=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:image","scott","tiger");
               s=c.createStatement();

               ps=c.prepareStatement("insert into ImageStoring values(?,?)");
               ps.setInt(1,2);
               ps.setBinaryStream(2,fis,(int)file.length());
               System.out.println("success");
               ps.execute();
               ps.close();
               c.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
               e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
```

Comment: Notice "Connection c" in your code which is java.sql.Connection;
so you get the native method of con.prepareStatement();
But in My Case Connection is an instance of DBConnection con;
DBConnection is a Custom Class for made by a previous developer.
Which do not has con.prepareStatement(); method

Comment: Hope i could.. 
It's a big big Class..
Around 6000 lines.
And contains some client info that's why either.
Can you give me your final SQL query?
So i can check it by running on Oracle.
So i could ensure that Database part is working fine